Slot as a parent of another slot in Vue
Essentially I am trying to write a tooltip component, and I would like for the tooltip dialogue to be absolutely positioned relative to the source of the tooltip. To accomplish this, I would need to wrap the dialog with the source and set the source to position:relative. The problem is that I would like for both the source and tooltip text to be slots/some form of HTML, so that I can pass arbitrary icons/formatted text.
I have already tried something like:
<slot name="source">
    <slot name="text"></slot>
</slot>

but from what I gather Vue won't allow this, as I wasn't able to find any examples of this in documentation and didn't work when I tried it. I've also looked into dynamic/higher order components, but from what it looks like in Vue you have to define a set of possible components/import all of these components beforehand and slots are meant to be a stand in for this pattern.
Edit:
Example usage of this component might look like the following:
<ToolTip>
    <template #source>
        <Icon/>
    </template>
    <template #text>
        <span> I am <b>bold</b> text </span>
    </template>
</ToolTip>

Where <Icon/> and <span/> can be arbitrary components/html. Alternatively, if some solution exists with higher order components, usage might look like
<ToolTip source="Icon">
    <span> I am <b>bold</b> text </span>
</ToolTip>

Where "Icon" might be the string identifier of some registered component or maybe a ref. I am not sure which I would prefer or whether either is more feasible than the other.

could you write template code how do you want to use this tooltip component?

Usage as requested by the OP after updating the question:
See on Vue SFC Playground
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import Tooltip from './Tooltip.vue';
import Icon from './Icon.vue';

const msg = ref('Hello World!')

</script>

<template>
    <tooltip>
      <template #tooltip>I am a <strong style="color: red">tooltip</strong></template>
      <icon/>
    </tooltip>
</template>

Tooltip.vue
<script setup>
import { h, ref, useSlots } from 'vue';
const $dialog = ref();

const slots = useSlots();
const render = (_, {slots: $slots}) => 
  slots.default().map(vnode => h(vnode, {
      style: {position: 'relative'},
      onMouseenter: () => {
        $dialog.value.style.top = $dialog.value.parentElement.offsetHeight + 5 + 'px';
        $dialog.value.show();
      },
      onMouseleave: () => $dialog.value.close()
    }, $slots.default));

</script>
<template>
  <render>
    <dialog ref="$dialog">
      <slot name="tooltip"/>
    </dialog>
  </render>
</template>


It's not clear how you'd want to use your tooltip component, but you can do it this way:
Vue SFC Playground
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import Tooltip from './Tooltip.vue';

const msg = ref('Hello World!')

</script>

<template>
  <h1>{{ msg }}
    <tooltip>I am a <strong style="color: red">tooltip</strong></tooltip>
  </h1>
</template>

Tooltip.vue
<script setup>
import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue';
const $dialog = ref();
onMounted(() => {
  const {value: dialog} = $dialog;
  const {parentElement: parent} = dialog;
  parent.style.position = 'relative';  // @todo set if it's static, add the check
  parent.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
    dialog.style.left = 0;
    dialog.style.top = parent.offsetHeight + 5 + 'px'
    dialog.show();
  });
  parent.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    dialog.close();
  });
});

</script>

<template>
  <dialog ref="$dialog">
    <slot />
  </dialog>
</template>


Does this solve the problem?


<div class="source" style="position:relative">
  <slot name="source"></slot>
  <div class="text" style="position:abslute">
    <slot name="text"></slot>
  </div>
</div>



